# basic auth not working in python hug

Tags: python, postman, hug

I'm trying to set up basic auth and testing with postman. The code snippet below returns null when tested with Postman with Username and Password set correctly in the Basic Auth section.
If I replace the `hug.authentication.verify` with my own function, it isn't even called (tested by putting print statements in). If I print `user` it shows as `None` on the console.

```
authentication = hug.authentication.basic(hug.authentication.verify("gordy","emily"))

@hug.get()
def token(user: hug.directives.user, requires=authentication):
    return user
```

Answer (score 0):

The `requires=authentication` needs to go inside the `hug.get` decorator.